# Need help repairing mac partitions

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, bootcamp, partition

In the process of trying to create a bootcamp partition I messed up my partitions. At this point, I just want to merge the empty 40GB drive with my main one, giving that storage back. Here is what I get when I run a diskutil list. I nuked whatever was on the disk partition beforehand.

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *251.0 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         202.0 GB   disk0s2
   3:       Microsoft Basic Data OSXRESERVED             8.0 GB     disk0s3
   4:                 Apple_APFS                         40.8 GB    disk0s4

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +202.0 GB   disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD            150.7 GB   disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 44.6 MB    disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                512.4 MB   disk1s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      2.1 GB     disk1s4

/dev/disk2 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0: EF57347C-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC                        *40.8 GB    disk2
```

To give a little bit more info on my mac:

The macOS partition is working, and I am using it to post this question. The laptop originally only had 1 hard drive, the stock one included in the model. I have included a picture of my system specs below.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In the Disk Utility app, Click the 'Partition' Toolbar button, then in the big pie chart in the revealed tab, click on the partition you want to erase, then click the minus button ('-') at the bottom of the chart. That partition will be deleted, and the other partition will be expanded to to include the newly-emptied space.

If you're doing this by command-line I think you can use the following (based on the diskutil output shown above):

```
diskutil mergePartitions JHFS+ "Macintosh HD" disk0s2 disk0s4
```

The third and fourth terms (JHFS+ "Macintosh HD") are actually dummy terms in this context; they are not used. Assuming that disk0s2 — the main partition — is in an expandable format, this should preserve everything in that partition and overwrite the other two. Per the diskutil man page:

> If `force` is not given, and the first partition has a resizable file
>   system (e.g. JHFS+), the file system will be preserved  and grown in a
>   data-preserving manner; your format and name parameters are ignored in
>   this case. [If] the first partition is not resizable, you are prompted
>   if you want to format.

Comment: This wouldn’t work as at the time, I was unable to remove the partition and was given the message “This partition cannot be removed as the previous one cannot be expanded.” Furthermore, it was my experience that deleting a partition did not cause the previous one to expand, but rather a new, empty volume to be created. I actually did end up fixing this and intended to write an answer tomorrow detailing how but unfortunately this was not it. Merge would also not work as my primary drive was encrypted.